# Turn key replacement for Iframe system

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, rest, iframe

Not really sure how to ask this question because I have a feeling it might start a debate.

Currently my company uses `<iframes>` to embed an e-shop on affiliate sites but they want to make the embedding more customizable. I'm kind of unsure exactly how to achieve this.

I was thinking about maybe making a Jquery plugin so they could just $('div').eshop(); or perhaps using `JSONP` to hand back a script. The orders from the e-shop need to be handed back to our server mostly like via a POST so that they can be validated and handled. Currently they simply use an `<iframe>` which loads the same e-shop page on all the affiliate sites.

Another idea I had was to offer these functions as a sort of service but I've never tried to write my own web service so I'm unsure if this type of thing is possible. Also because embeding an `<iframe>` can be done in literally a few lines and requires minimal development effort on the customers end.. I would like to reproduce something that is almost as turn key as an `<iframe>`. (basically cut and paste these lines into your page and you'll have access to the e-shop on your site)

Suggestions?

Comment: I figured it might get closed but I'm not sure where to ask this. Would it be better in Meta?